# present tense of "deceive" in this sentence using "속았으며"

Tags: verb, conjugation, passive

I'm taking this sentence and making it present tense, but the verb may be taking the passive form (`피동사`) here, so I'm unsure of the dictionary form since I don't know if it's passive.

*Please don't explain `~(으)며` as that is not my question...i understand the meaning of `~(으)며` and only need help with changing `속았..` to present tense (when used in conjunction with `~(으)며` of course).*

Original sentence:

> 우리도 전에는 어리석었고 불순종하였고 **속았으며** ...마음으로 서로 미워하며 살았습니다.

My best effort:

> 우리도 어리석이고 불순종하고 **속이며** ...마음으로 서로 미워하며 삽니다.

To summarize, in "my best effort" is **`속이며`** correct? And, is the dictionary form `속이다` or `속다` in this case?

Comment: You may say "우리도 어리**석게 굴**고 불순종하고 속**임을 당하**며...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

속이다 is actually the causative form (사동사) of 속다, not the passive.  It's quite confusing sometimes, as the same ending 이다 is the passive suffix for some verbs but the causative suffix for others.  In the case of 속다/속이다, 속다 is intransitive and means "be tricked, be deceived".  It usually goes with a noun with the ending 에/에게 to indicate "by whom":

> 그는 사기꾼에게 속았다 He was fooled by the con artist.

So  속이다 means to trick/deceive someone; it is a transitive verb, and I don't think it's what you want to say.

It seems you meant to say in the first sentence "we were deceived", but it's a bit unclear in Korean without saying by whom; so you might say "사탄에게 속았으며 (deceived by satan; maybe I'm wrong but it seems like it's from a sermon so perhaps that's what is meant).

In that case, the second sentence should use 속다 not 속이다, and it should still be in the past tense, because even though the sentence is present, the deception began in the past, so it makes sense still to use the past tense form.  So this might make sense:

> 우리도 어리석고 불순종하고 (사탄에게) 속았으며 마음으로 서로 미워하며 삽니다.

Comment: Interesting, so if we were the deceivers deceiving other humans, then would 속였으며 be correct?  Thank you